# Do Azure Functions retry policies count towards billing and timeouts?

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-functions

Microsoft have recently released [retry policies for Azure Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-error-pages?tabs=csharp#retry-policies-preview) (preview), which can be applied using the `FixedDelayRetry` and `ExponentialBackoffRetry` attributes. Do these retry policies hook into the Azure Functions runtime and operate at a level below the function invocations, or are they effectively the same as an `await Task.Delay` in user-code? Specifically, would the retry delays of these policies count towards the function execution time, and hence be billed and cause timeouts if they exceed the [10-minute maximum duration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-host-json#functiontimeout) on consumption plan?

I can only find the following [relevant method](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/blob/3f4ec78be9f43bb041937425ced00b341883aa42/src/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host/Executors/FunctionExecutorExtensions.cs#L72) in the source code (simplified version below), which enforces retry delays using an `await Task.Delay`, but I might be missing something.

```cs
namespace Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors
{
    internal static class FunctionExecutorExtensions
    {
        public static async Task<IDelayedException> TryExecuteAsync(this IFunctionExecutor executor, Func<IFunctionInstance> instanceFactory, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            var attempt = 0;

            while (true)
            {
                var functionInstance = instanceFactory.Invoke();
                var functionException = await executor.TryExecuteAsync(functionInstance, cancellationToken);

                if (functionException == null)
                    return null;   // function invocation succeeded
                if (functionInstance.FunctionDescriptor.RetryStrategy == null)
                    return functionException;   // retry is not configured

                var retryStrategy = functionInstance.FunctionDescriptor.RetryStrategy;
                if (retryStrategy.MaxRetryCount != -1 && ++attempt > retryStrategy.MaxRetryCount)
                    return functionException;   // retry count exceeded

                TimeSpan nextDelay = retryStrategy.GetNextDelay(retryContext);
                await Task.Delay(nextDelay);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

There are many shortcomings in other aspects of these retry policies, so unless they offer some advantage through their integration with the functions runtime, I'd prefer to stick with a mature reusable library such as [Polly](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly).

- The retry policies cannot be customized. `ExponentialBackoffRetry` uses a [hardcoded factor](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/blob/3f4ec78be9f43bb041937425ced00b341883aa42/src/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host/Timers/RandomizedExponentialBackoffStrategy.cs#L74) of 2 that cannot be changed. `FixedDelayRetry` does not support random jitter, and `ExponentialBackoffRetry` has a [hardcoded random jitter](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/blob/3f4ec78be9f43bb041937425ced00b341883aa42/src/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host/Timers/RandomizedExponentialBackoffStrategy.cs#L11) of ±20%.
- Retry failures get logged as errors, needlessly cluttering the error logs. It doesn't seem possible to disable these retry errors without losing all other function errors too.
- There is no way of getting the retry count. [`RetryContext`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/issues/2595) still gives a binding error on the latest non-beta packages.
- Technical documentation is sparse, with the above details needing to be inferred from the source code.